# CGAL: Modify an extended DCEL fetched from a locate call

Tags: c++, cgal

I have an `Arrangement_2` class, instantiated with a custom `Arr_face_extended_dcel` to map some data to each cell.

I'd like to find some cells with a `locate` invocation and change their associated data, but unfortunately `locate` returns an iterator to some `Face_const_handle`s, so I can't invoke `set_data(...)` because that would break the `const`ness.

So, my question: is there a way to efficiently change the data mapped to a face found with a `locate` without resorting to nasty `const_cast`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the overloaded member template functions `non_const_handle()` of the `Arrangement_2` template class. There are 3 versions, which accept `Vertex_const_handle`, `Halfedge_const_handle`, and `Face_const_handle`, respectively; see the [manual](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arrangement__2.html).

BW, `const_cast<>` will not work. because, for example, `Vertex_const_handle` and `Vertex_handle` are simply different types.